# DC offset in closed-loop ideal op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, input-offset-voltage

It's from Sedra. It's about how the offset current messes with the input of an inverter. It's "easily seen", but no so for me. Can anyone explain to my "not easily seen" brain how the output is $$V_{out} = V_{off}(1 + \frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}})\text{?}$$

Thanks a bunch!

[image: The circuit in question]

Comment: Your picture shows offset voltage; your text says offset current. You need to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I understood it now. It's just an inverter, and you make the inputs equal (because it's ideal). So:

$$R_{2} \cdot V^{-} = R_{1}\cdot(V_{out} - V^{-})$$

where because of the ideal op-amp abstraction:

$$V^{-} = V_{off} = V^{+}$$

So you substitute this on the first equation and get

$$V_{out} = V_{out}\cdot(\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}} + 1)$$

That was easy. But the book should explicitly say that this configuration can be dealt with as the usual inverter.

Comment: This expression (1+R2/R1) is called "noise gain" - and it applies to the inverter as well as non-inverer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the added knowledge. Yes, I also realized it happened to the non-inverter configuration.